# How to install Lua Love using the luarocks manger?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am a complete newb to lua, but so far I like it.

I want to install love because it provides a nice framework and want to explore its features. I can already run lua scripts (luarocks comes with lua5.1.) and I have the zerobrain IDE. I installed socket.rock by getting the .rock file and running:

`luarocks install luasocket-2.0.2-3.win32-x86.rock`

But I can't find a similar file for love. I found this website: [luarocks-love](https://luarocks.org/m/love), which tells me:

`luarocks install --server=http://luarocks.org/m/love <name>`

So I can run this, but I don't know what `<name>` means... I tried it without `<name>` and I get an error. Can someone explain what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Love via luarocks. Love isn't a library.

The installers for Windows are available [here](https://love2d.org/).

What you have there is just used for installing libraries using luarocks that depend upon Love. It is not the framework itself.

Comment: Thanks ktb, I am bit confused - I thought Lua was the language (i.e. like c++), things like sockets are libraries (like boost libraries in c++), so how does lua love interact with lua and the libraries that I already have? - is it a separate language entirely?

Comment: From my understanding Love is a application that make many graphics routines that are written in another language (probably C) scriptable using Lua. Using Lua as a scripting language embedded in other application is a very common use of the language. Many video games use Lua for scripting, you can see it as something similar, but a game engine instead of a full game.

Comment: Ok thanks for that information. I think I need to install Love then and have a play with it and see how I can combine the two : )